# General SVM implementation

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I want to learn **General SVM** implementation which uses **QP** problem for training. Initially I do not  want to learn Sequential minimal Optimization(SMO) kind of algorithm which over comes the QP matrix size issue. Can any one please give me some references to learn **Pure General SVM implementation** in any programming languages like **C,C++ or Java**. So that I can understand basic issues in SVM and it will help me in learning some other SVM optimized algorithms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [blog post by Mathieu Blondel](http://www.mblondel.org/journal/2010/09/19/support-vector-machines-in-python/) explains how to solve the SVM problem both with and without kernels using a generic QP solver in Python (in this case he is using CVXOPT).

The source code is published on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/586753) and is very simple to understand thanks to the numpy array notation for n-dimensional arrays (in this case, mostly 2D matrices and 1D vectors).

Answer (score 1):

You could check some of the resources mentioned [here](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-book-on-Support-Vector-Machines). It is also advisable to have a look at the existing code. One of the most popular implementations, [LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/), is open-source, so you can study the implementation.

Comment: Hi Qnan, I have referred LIBSVM as you suggested...In LIBSVM I could see SMO-type decomposition method(Working Set Selection Using Second Order Information for Training Support Vector Machines) while training. Is it kind of General SVM implementation?.

Comment: LIBSVM is precisely implementing the SVM-specific optimizer that OP is not interested in, namely Sequential minimal Optimization(SMO).

Comment: @ogrisel it does say "initially" there